# Разноцветное облако тегов WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Необходимо вывести все имеющиеся в WP теги, с помощью функции `wp_tag_cloud()` либо её подфункций, добавив к каждому тегу **class** от "с1" до "с10" (в зависимости от количества записей в теге), для того, чтобы потом раскрасить это облако через **CSS**.

Подобный функционал я нашел лишь в плагине "Simple Tags", но при посещаемости 5000 человек в день, он отжирает CPU на 100%. А выдернуть нужный код из него, мне не хватило знаний.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: можно нужные классы js ом добавить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо получить значения меток в массив и обработать его. Например, так:

```
$cloud = wp_tag_cloud("echo=false&format=array");
foreach ($cloud as &$tag) {
    $pos = strpos($tag, "title='");
    $title = substr($tag, $pos + 7);
    $pos = strpos($title, " ");
    $add_class = "c" . substr($title, 0, $pos);
    $tag = str_replace("class='", "class='" . $add_class . " ", $tag);
    echo $tag;
}
```

Comment: Вариант не плохой, только надо брать не число записей в теге, а значение font-size

Comment: так в в вопросе было озвучено как раз число записей в теге ))